# Design pattern to access multiple different data sources

Tags: design-patterns

I have a case where I need to read/query from a sybase database and then manipulate this retrieved data and write them to our own custom datasource which is an xml based persistent store(Not files). We have our own APIs to save/retrieve information to/from our data source (This is neither a database nor a file). We have our own APIs to read and write to this custom datasource (persistent)

Would you be able to suggest a generic design pattern to handle such cases? Also, a skeleton code snippet as an example would be much appreciated.

PS: Today it is sybase tomorrow we might move on to some other db.

Thanks,
J

Comment: database provider factory ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what the [Data Access Object (DAO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) pattern is for. It abstracts away from specific details about the underlying data source whatever it is: a database, xml files, etc.